# why this javascript code don't pass but the other one does, if they generate the same output. (reduce vs for)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm taking the adventJS  [challenge #2](https://adventjs.dev/challenges/02):

> You have received a letter ✉️ with all the gifts you must prepare. The issue is that it is a string of text and is very difficult to read . Fortunately they have separated each gift by a space! (although **be careful**, because being children, they might have inserted more spaces than needed)
>
> What's more, we have noticed that some words come with a `_` in front of the word, for example `_playstation`, which means that it **is striked out and should not be counted**.
>
> Transform the text to an object that contains the name of each gift and the times it appears. For example, if we have the text:
>
> ```
> const carta = 'bici coche balón _playstation bici coche peluche'
> ```
>
> running the method should return the following:
>
> ```
> const regalos = listGifts(carta)
>
> console.log(regalos)
> /*
> {
>   bici: 2,
>   coche: 2,
>   balón: 1,
>   peluche: 1
> }
> */
> ```
>
> Keep in mind that the tests can be more exhaustive...  Beware of counting empty spaces!

My code does not pass the tests, but it should work:

```js
const carta = 'bici coche balón _playstation bici     coche peluche'

function listGifts(letter) {
  rta = letter.split(/\s+/).reduce(function(acc,value){
    const g = acc[value]
    if(!g){
      if(!value.includes("_")){
        acc[value]=1
      }
    }else{
      acc[value]=g+1
    }
    return acc
  },{});
  return rta;
}

console.log(listGifts(carta))
```

But this code passes:

```js
const carta = 'bici coche balón _playstation bici     coche peluche'

function listGifts2(letter) {

    let palabras = letter.split(" ")
    let lista = {};
    
    for(let i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++){
        if (!palabras[i].includes("_")){
            if(lista[palabras[i]]==undefined){
                lista[palabras[i]] = 1
            } else {
                lista[palabras[i]] += 1
            }
        }
    }
    delete lista[""]
    return lista
}

console.log(listGifts2(carta))
```

I don't understand. I use the same condition, the same data types.
Even if I change the regex, to coincide with the correct code, it still doesn't work:

```js
const carta = 'bici coche balón _playstation bici     coche peluche'

function listGifts(letter) {
  const carta = letter.split(" ")
  
  rta = carta.reduce(function(acc,value){
    const g = acc[value]
    if(!g){
      if(!value.includes("_")){
        acc[value]=1
      }
    }else{
      acc[value]=g+1
    }
    return acc
  },{});
  delete rta[""]
  return rta;
}

console.log(listGifts(carta))
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. What does "not accepted" mean? Do you get an error message when you submit the code? What is this error message? Please edit your question to add the error message. Also, what makes you believe that your code works? Did you test it? What were the results of the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference is that the first version may return an object that has an empty string as property:

```
{ "": 1 }
```

This happens when the input string starts with a space or ends with a space or is the empty string.

So either include that `delete` operation also in your first version, or use any other way to avoid that an empty string appears as a property in your final object.

Remark: the description says that a word should be ignored when it *starts* with an underscore. That means that `a_b` should not be excluded. So you should not use `includes` but test the very first character is not an underscore.

Comment: yes!!, that is it, if a run a test with the string = '"', my version return {''":1} but the other one return {}